# Prime generating modular function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I found that

$(671n \mod 2454) + (304n \mod 32) + (4373n \mod 199)$

generates $38$ distinct primes for $n=1$ to $38$: $881, 1531, 2213, 409, 1091, 1741, 2423, 619, 1301, 1951, 179, 829, 1511, 2161, 389, 1039, 1721, 2371, 599, 1249, 1931, 127, 809, 1459, 2141, 337, 1019, 1669, 2351, 547, 1229, 1879, 107, 757, 1439, 2089, 317, 967.$

Is this anything unusual and is there a good explanation for it? Is there a function of the same form that generates more consecutive terms of distinct primes? The function must be of the form  $\sum_{i}(A_in \mod B_i)$, where all $A_i, B_i$  are positive integers.

Comment: How did you find this formula ?

Comment: I used hill climbing to find this formula. Each move consists of changing one of the 6 variables. I believe better formulas exist though.

Comment: A kind of genetic algorithm. Well done ! I think, it will be hard to beat this, but I share your expectation that it can be beaten.

Comment: The last two summands are simpler as $\  16(n\bmod 2) + (-5n\bmod 199)\ \ $

Comment: By the way if we have $An \mod B$ then we can generate any arithmetic progression. So this will allow us to get 27 primes in arithmetic progression - current record from Rob Gahan.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I have doubts that this can actually be done. Please work out this claim a bit more.

Comment: for example $(257n \mod 287)$ produces 257 227 197 167 137 107, which is an arithmetic progression with a difference of 30.

Comment: In other words $(An \mod A+D)$ will generate $A, A+D, A+2D, ...$, so any arithmetic progression.

Comment: This modular function can also be written as: ((666n+199) mod 2454)+16(n mod 2). Written this way it will generate 41 distinct primes for n=-2 to 38 (primes for -2 to 0: 
1321, 2003 and 199. All other values identical to the original function.

Comment: @pietfermat this is a great find! 41 primes is starting to approach the best results for prime generating polynomials. Can we do better? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky $An\mod (A+D)$ does not generate $A,A+D,A+2D,\cdots$ , but $A,A-D,A-2D,\cdots$. The start value in your example is $17$. So, how do I have to choose the paramters to get a desired start value ?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I am not sure whether the expressions you are interested can be transformed into poylnomials and vice versa. And if I understand the question correctly, we always start with $n=1$ and want to have as many primes as possible. I mention this because pietfermat began with $-2$ to get even more primes.

Comment: Of course you are right, the sequence is $A, A-D, A-2D, ...$. My mistake. I guess any sequence of values can be generated with a polynomial, but that's not very interesting. The more interesting question is whether these general functions can be converted to polynomials.

Comment: @Peter we can of course change pietfermat's function so it starts with $n=1$ by subtracting 3 from $n$: $(666n-1799) \mod 2454+16((n-3) \mod 2)$. If you don't like minuses, this can be converted to $(666n+655) \mod 2454+16((n+1) \mod 2)$. Finally I did manage to find a function of the original form that produces 41 primes: $(n*639)\mod 558 + (n*355)\mod 344 + (n*1124)\mod 1066 + (n*1294)\mod1230 + (n*175)\mod 179$.

Comment: Let $C\gt A(B-1)$ and $n\lt B$. Then, $$(An\bmod C)+(n \bmod B)+((B-1)n \bmod B)=An+B.$$ We can get $k$ primes in arithmetic progression for any $k$, according to Green-Tao theorem. The theorem is not constructive and the [current record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression#Largest_known_primes_in_AP) is $k=27$.